# select all parents and childs from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am using C# and I have Question and Answers tables in database. I want to get all questions and answers from database. Should I select the questions to list first and then get answers or should I do it with one query, using JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

A round trip to the database is extremely costly (performance wise), so you definitely want to avoid [the SELECT N+1 problem](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/selectnplusone). Normally, your ORM should give you the features to fetch everything in one go.

However, make sure to also limit the result set (using paging/batching techniques). Fetching too much data at once can also get you in trouble.